# I want to need android download manager application. i was finished up to my Knoweldge

Tags: android

Now i have one edit text and one button. i am copy the download link from the browser and paste it to the edit text it perfectly work. but i want to need if user using any browser and they click the download link the file will be download via my app.

Comment: bro's i don't know why you are giving downvote for my question plzzzz share me too. I think my bad english because i am from village guy,if you are in good in english plzzz try to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to have intent filter in your download activity inside manifest like this

```
<activity
        android:name="Downloader">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="domain.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then inside your "Download" activity's onCreate handle data:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Uri data = intent.getData();
}
```

You can download file using uri